# Simple Django program causing me trouble

Tags: python, django

I've gone through quite a few django tutorials, and I'm finally getting ready to head out on my own.  However, my first non-tutorial program is throwing an error, and I've been banging my head for a couple of days.  I expect it to be a very noob problem, because, well, I am.

When I use this view

```
 def todo(request): 
        latest_list = Item.objects.all()
        return HttpResponse(latest_list)
```

I get

```
conquer djangocan I do this?learn thislearn this
```

which are the four items that populate the database.  Not very handy since they are concatenated, and they don't appear to be handed off to the template.

When I change my view.py to try to talk to the template using

```
def todo(request):
        latest_list = Item.objects.all()
        return render_to_response,('index.html', {"latest_list", latest_list})
```

I get

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Could it be that the model that's returning 'self.task' is limiting the return to only that field?  Other tutorial I looked at seemed to return only one value (and returning just 'self' gets me a very similar error.

It could also be that I'm not passing in

Any help that would push me down the correct path would be greatly appreciated.

Greg

My model.py

---

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    taskNotes = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.task
```

---

My views.py

---

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse
from myToDo.todo.models import Item

def todo(request): 
    latest_list = Item.objects.all()
    return HttpResponse(latest_list)
```

---

My index.html (template)

---

```
{% if latest_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for task in latest_list %}
        <li>{{ Item.task }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>Looks like you're all done</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return render_to_response,('index.html', {"latest_list", latest_list})
```

Remove that comma affer render_to_response and you should be ok. Reason: the comma makes the return value a tuple object, but need to return an HttpResponse object from a view.

Answer (score 1):

You goofed on your `return`.

```
def todo(request):
  latest_list = Item.objects.all()
  return render_to_response('index.html', {"latest_list", latest_list})
```

Note the lack of comma after the function name.