# Django got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an archive so I pass to the view the arguments year and month.

However, I get an error with the code below and I can't figure out what it means and how to solve it:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    archive() got an unexpected keyword argument 'year_id'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 115
```

What can be wrong?

**views.py**

```
    # loop over years and months
def mkmonth_lst():
    if not Post.objects.count():
        return []
    # set up vars
    year, month = time.localtime()[:2]
    first = Post.objects.order_by("created")[0]
    fyear = first.created.year
    fmonth = first.created.month
    months = []

    # loop over years and months
    for y in range(year, fyear-1, -1):
        start, end = 12, 0
        if y == year: start = month
        if y == fyear: end = fmonth-1

        for m in range(start, end, -1):
            months.append((y, m, month_name[m]))

    return months

def archive(request, year, month):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(created__year=year, created__month=month)
    context = {'PostList': posts, 'Months': mkmonth_lst()}

    return(render, 'archives.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^archives/(?P<year_id>\d+)/(?P<month_id>\d+)$', views.archive, name='archives'),
```

Update:

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to = 'video', verbose_name = 'Video', null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'post', verbose_name = 'Picture')
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Template

```
<h3>Archivo</h3>
  <p>
    {% for month in months %}
        {% ifchanged month.0 %} {{ month.0 }} <br /> {% endifchanged %}
            <a href="/blog/archives/{{month.0}}/{{month.1}}">{{ month.2 }}</a> <br />
    {% endfor %}
  </p>
```

Update 2: error

```
usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
            response = middleware_method(request, response) ...
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py in process_response
    if response.status_code == 404: ...


Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archives/2014/1
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'tuple' object has no attribute 'status_code'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py   in process_response, line 106
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/fernando/develop/blogmanage',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_mptt-0.6.0-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
Server time:    Wed, 29 Jan 2014 21:09:56 +0100
```

Comment: The URL captures a variable "year_id", but your view takes the argument "year".

Comment: That's right! Now I get a new error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is something wrong with your parameters names :

```
 def archive(request, year, month):
```

Replace `year` and `month` by `year_id` and `month_id` and it should work.

EDIT:

For your second error, and accordingly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194117/simple-django-program-causing-me-trouble), your `archive()` view does not return a proper response.

Here is your code, fixed :

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def archive(request, year_id, month_id):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(created__year=year_id, created__month=month_id)
    context = {'PostList': posts, 'Months': mkmonth_lst()}

    # the error was here
    return render_to_response('archives.html', context)
```

Edit 2 :

Your template can't iterate through  `months` because the var does not exist in context:

```
context = {'PostList': posts, 'Months': mkmonth_lst()} # Not correct
context = {'postList': posts, 'months': mkmonth_lst()} # Correct
```

Do you see the difference ? You use caps for your variables names ("Months") in the first one, while the template rendered, which is case-sensitive, looks for a lower case variable ("months").

Comment: That's right! Now the error is: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Comment: Please, paste the whole stacktrace and/or the code in which it happens =)

Comment: Thanks that fix my problem, but now the web browser doesn't show the template complete, only load a part of it.

Comment: I think the error is located in `mkmonth_lst()`. However, I don't understand your goal with this function, so I can't help, sorry =/

Comment: My goal is to create an archive. I follow this tutotial http://lightbird.net/dbe/blog2.html but I have problems to adapt the archive view to my blog app.

Comment: As far as I understand, I suppose you can't iterate through months in your template because `mkmonth_st()` return an empty list. Do you have any blog post in your database ?

Comment: Yes I don't know why the web browser only show the half of the template. I'll investigate what is wrong. If if i get the solution I will post! Thanks for all!!

Comment: Look at my last edit, it should solve your problem ;)

Comment: This solve part of the problem. The problem is when I use {% extends "base.html" %} the web browser only shows a part of this "base.html". For example: the logo doesn't appear...

Comment: I suggest you open a new thread for this question, so that you can paste your whole template code.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it was a typo for using `:` instead of `=` in the model definition.

Eg it was:

```
class Workspace(models.Model):
    title: models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description: models.CharField(max_length=2000)
...
```

But should be:

```
class Workspace(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
...
```